# PrettyLinkPro API PHP Question

Tags: php, wordpress

So in a wordpress blog using prettylinkpro plugin, I found a link to the author's site about an API.

http://blairwilliams.com/pretty-link/api/

I'm trying to get a post's "pretty link" using the prli_get_link($slug) method.

Problem is, I believe that is returning an array, and I'm not verse in PHP.

So I think I'm looking for something like this:

prli_get_link($slug)[0]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's parser doesn't allow direct array references on function returns, so

```
prli_get_link($slug)[0]
```

is a syntax error. You have to assign to an intermediate variable instead:

```
$link_array = prli_get_link($slug);
$first_item = $link_array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

i didn't not understand what you are talking about
but generaly try this code to see the output of almost anything in php

```
var_dump(prli_get_link($slug));
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I used it elsewhere!